# Order by Desc and Asc in DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, decimal, sql-order-by

I am using DB Browser for SQLite, (Version 3.10.0, Qt Version 5.7.1, SQLCipher Version 3.15.2) and I have a column that I want to sort with the highest values first. I used:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, Totalclaims
FROM workingdata
ORDER BY Totalclaims Desc;
```

The problem is that my query has `$993.00` being seen as greater than `$9920.00`. Apparently the filter is not recognizing the decimal place properly. Any advice how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure Totalclaims column is stored like a float? Are you sure is not a varchar?

Comment: Try with `ORDER BY cast(replace(Totalclaims,'$','') as float) Desc;`

Comment: @tonypdmtr no need to do that, you can check the length of the varchar first, that should be much quicker than replacing the dollars and converting to float.

Comment: But it will still work if some entries have a `$` and some don't, or `999.00` and `998.0000`.

Comment: @tonypdmtr if some items have euros or pounds, then replacing the dollar will not work. All the examples contain dollars, so it is safe to assume the records contain dollars until the op says otherwise.

Comment: And what about varying decimal digits?

Comment: @tonypdmtr the situation is the same. Nothing was specified and seeing the examples it is safe to assume that all the data have two decimals. If not, then the op should tell us that. Up until that I will assume he has two decimals.

Comment: Thank you both. ORDER BY cast(replace(Totalclaims,'$','') as float) Desc; worked just fine for what I needed. I will have to study this line to get better at writing code. For the record, this is an R output, written to a CSV, and has up to 14 (i think) decimal places. Again very grateful to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

– tonypdmtr wrote: 
Try with 
ORDER BY cast(replace(Totalclaims,'$','') as float) Desc;

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Clean out the Totalclaims column and this should order it for you.

```
   SELECT first_name, last_name, cast(replace(Totalclaims,'$', '') as SIGNED) as TotalClaims_Clean
    FROM workingdata
    ORDER BY Totalclaims_Clean Desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have two decimal places, then order by length of `Totalclaims` first and then after `Totalclaims`.

EDIT:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, Totalclaims
FROM workingdata
ORDER BY length(Totalclaims) desc, Totalclaims Desc;
```